# android read org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File) from assets

Tags: android, parsing, apache-commons, assets, text-files

I am trying to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File) to read a text file from android assets into a byte array.

I cant seem to find the way to return a File Object from assets.

Any ideas?

Comment: not clear. how did you make your file object? show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a file object from your assets folder you can do this :

```
File f= new File("file:///android_asset/","yourFile.txt");
```